# How to rename angular app?

Tags: angular, web, rename

I have an angular app which I'd like to rename. Is there an easy way to rename the app other than renaming manually all the occurrences of the app name (like the `folder name`, in `package.json`, etc..)

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that doing the rename manually is actually less work than asking this question here.

Comment: probably :) I wanted to know if there's a best practice out there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot !!

By default, Angular will create a project/app using name/alias `app` But after creating a new project if you wish to change the **selectors** for new component/service etc.

Then you can change the configuration in `.angular-cli.json` file under the

```
"prefix": "app",  //change with your name here
```

Comment: @SahilBabbar Just read my answer again, I already mentioned It will rename your new component after creating a project. and Nowhere mentioned that it will rename whole app.

Comment: During the creation of the project you can specify --prefix="your-selector-prefix" to set the default prefix for your app. You will still need to rename the folder which angular creates for you (app).
ref: [link](https://angular.io/cli/new#options)