# How to rename angular 6 project name?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

How to rename Angular 6 project name, please?

When I do a search for the project name, it has 16 results in 6 files.
If I just renamed will it all work fine?

Or do I need to create a new project with the new name and then move the files?

[image]

Comment: Try and tell us :)

Comment: Seems link a duplicate... [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891832/how-to-rename-an-angular4-angular2-project-folder/49251979) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445373/how-to-rename-angular-app)

Comment: @Eric Thanks, I have checked those already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my screenshot in the original question, I did search & replace the old project name with the new name, in all those 16 results from 6 files.

And I renamed the project folder name with the new name. It works as expected so far.

Comment: I was trying to install pwa feature to an angular 6 app, and did not create/update the expected files. Turned out the base app name was a different one than the intended one (it was a cloned repo that had the root folder renamed), and doing a name replace fixed it.